# How to change login properites

Tags: login

I didn't realize when I installed with automatic login that doing so would defeat the option to login to the Afterstep desktop. How do I correct this?
Thank You.

Comment: Simply don't use automatic login.

Comment: ^--- interpreted: Revert the change for automatic login

Comment: OK I have removed auto login & I now use my password. The Afterstep desktop is said to be a default installation now, whereas once it was not default. It is supposed to be an option when logging in but NO option appears? Why? Can it be made to appear?

Comment: I have no options on the login menu for 22.04  Is there any way to activate it?